# Send email via SES

Tags: python, django, email, amazon-ses

Do I need an actual mailbox and verified email to send email with SES?

I own the domain I am trying to send from, but I do not have an account or mailbox setup (this is just a test domain, and I don't want to setup a gmail mailbox)

Is there a better way to be doing this in a test environment?

I am using the django-ses package, and sending email like this:

send_mail('Test subject', 'This is the body', 'mypersonalemail@yahoo.com',['info@mydomain.com'])

I very well may have a fundamental misunderstanding of sending email, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the test environment, you can send messages e-mail only to address registered in sandbox.

Comment: @Agnelo what sending address should I use?

Comment: The receiver's email must be registered with SES. It could be any email.

Comment: but what about the sender? Does it need to be an actual address with a mailbox?

Comment: the sender could be anyone, but it's interesting that you put a valid email to know if it's really working. The same goes for the sender, puts a personal email. You can see the response of the request, but it is important to check the mailbox as well.

Comment: In production environment, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html

Answer (score 1):

At first, you need to verify domain or email address to send from Amazon SES. But you don't need to verify address whom you want to send.

For example,

```
     send_mail('Test subject', 'This is the body', 'mypersonalemail@yahoo.com', 
               ['info@mydomain.com'])
```

Here, you need to verify mypersonalemail@yahoo.com at AWS SES, not info@mydomail.com.

Comment: thanks, I marked the other answer as correct, but this is right too.